# Poudre de perlimpinpin

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Maintenant je comprends ce que [cette expression](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/perlimpinpin) veut dire.

Mais je voudrais savoir aussi si le mot *perlimpinpin*, indépendamment de cette expression, a un sens. Ou est-ce un *nonce word* qui n'a aucun sens par lui-même?

Comment: Comme indiqué dans le lien, « perlimpinpin », en tant que tel, n'est jamais employé. Il n'aurait donc aucun sens excepté dans l'expression « poudre de perlimpinpin. »

Comment: It’s probably just a thing in my wife’s weird family (de l’Oise/Picardie), but she claims that standing alone/independantly it can mean cotton candy (*Barbe à papa*) and also that as a [weird] child she used to stick it nonsensically after words that rhyme with *pin*, kind of like a rhyming rim shot for emphasis (eg, “C’est loin, [perlim]pinpin).

Comment: @PapaPoule If that rhyme were preceded by _en_, that would turn it into a minced oath imho. Do you think _tiddy fol lol_ is construed as rhyming with everything? Thanks.

Comment: @Voléedechênesetrosiers Good catch! Maybe "... kind of like an **assonant** rim shot for emphasis" would have been a better choice of words (but now I'm not even sure if that word is right either)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'expression « poudre de perlimpinpin » fait référence aux diverses poudres vendues jadis par des bonimenteurs et charlatans, qui les présentaient comme dotées de vertus merveilleuses et guérissant toute sorte de maux, alors qu'elles n'avaient aucun effet bénéfique.

Le nom fantaisiste de « perlimpinpin » serait une onomatopée dont la sonorité évoque une formule magique à l'instar de "Abracadabra".

"Perlimpinpin" est un mot qui date de la première moitié du XVIIe siècle mais dont l'étymologie est inconnue. Il s'est aussi écrit "prelimpinpin".

Sources : [Poudre de perlimpinpin (Wikipedia)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poudre_de_perlimpinpin)
[Poudre de perlimpinpin (Expression.fr)](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/la-poudre-de-perlimpinpin.php)

Comment: C'est très intéressant vraiment.

Comment: Une curiosité, mais vous avez trois sortes de guillemets dans votre réponse, il y a une raison en particulier ? N'hésitez pas à inclure le lien vers [_abracadabra_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abracadabra) au besoin. Merci !

Answer (score 3):

Non, à ma connaissance, ce mot n'a aucun sens en dehors de cette expression !